# Proper usage of 'to do so'

Tags: word-usage

> It is not necessary to initialize variables. However, it is not a good practice to do so.

I'm not sure if the sentence i wrote convey the meaning i intend to. What is understood from the sentence above:  'it is good practice to initialize' or 'it is NOT a good practice to initialize'

any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, *do so* substitutes for *initialize variables*:

> It is not necessary to **initialize variables**. However, it is not a good practice to **initialize variables**.
>   It is not necessary to **initialize variables**. However, it is not a good practice to **do so**.

But this seems like the opposite of what you intended to say.  Let's remove *not*:

> It is not necessary to **initialize variables**. However, it is a good practice to **initialize variables**.
>   It is not necessary to **initialize variables**. However, it is a good practice to **do so**.

This seems like what you wanted to say.

Comment: Or of course "it is not a good practice **not** to do so."

Comment: Or "It is not necessary to initialize variables, but it is good practice to do so anyway."