# Non-deontic uses of "should have done"

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, tense-agreement

> 1. Next day we got on to more intimate subjects and I began to learn
>      something of his life. He was now nearer fifty than forty years of
>      age, though I **should have thought** him younger.
> 2. I had been surprised on the evening of our first meeting to discover
>      the nature of his work. He was engaged in selling sewing machines on
>      commission to Indian storekeepers up and down the East African coast.
>      It was clearly not the job for which his age and education
>      **should have fitted** him. Later I learned the explanation.
>
> Source: [Too Much Tolerance](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0316216569), by [Evelyn Waugh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Waugh)

I guess in the first example **should have thought**  should be equivalent to **would have thought**, but I was wondering if **"thought" or "had thought"** could be used instead without changing the intended meaning.

As for the second example, I would think **"should fit"** should be used instead because obviously he was still engaged in his sales job at the narrative time. Does this **should have done** construction here imply an unfulfilled expectation?

If I cast this example into the present, will it be "It is clearly not the job for which his age and education **should fit** him."?

Comment: This seems a bit stilted, dated - is this from a historic narrative? Or perhaps a translation from another language? At the very least, this discourse is highly unusual.

Comment: No, Evelyn Waugh is thought to be one of the century's great masters of English prose. @jimsug

Comment: I see - it looks like he wrote during the sixties (at the latest!) which confirms my instincts. And I notice you didn't mention _which_ century ;)

Comment: My bad, it's last century. You mean these two usages are out-of-date? One would not see them in contemporary articles? @jimsug

Comment: At the very least it would be considered unusual, perhaps a bit... upper-class? It's a bit ineffable, but I can stretch my imagination to conceive of someone (probably Britsh, for some reason) using this kind of language.

Comment: Concurrence with @jimsug; the first thing I thought of when I imagined a situation where language of this form would be used is _Downton Abbey_ - a British period drama set in the early 1900s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only read these passages with a somewhat colonial-era mindset - that is, the language seems to be from a few decades ago, or *maybe* present-day Britain (I'm not sure, I wasn't there long enough last time).

In any case:

1. He was now nearer fifty than forty years of age, though I should have thought him younger.

   In this case, *should* is being used to express that the thought "he is younger than 50" was the more *appropriate* thought.

   As for whether or not you can remove *should* and *have* and keep the meaning: *should* usually reduces certainty - conveys conditionality upon another circumstance.

   However, in this case it appears to express *propriety*, which is a meaning that you're unlikely to glean from the text if you're not a native speaker. I would say that *today*, you could remove *should* and have the same meaning, but in the register of the pre-1960s, I'm not sure that's the case (and I believe that that's off-topic here).

   For removing *have*, this would be a distinction between using the *simple past* and the *pluperfect*, where the simple past merely refers to an action completed (sometimes habitually) in the past.

   The pluperfect refers to an action completed in the past, at a time earlier than the time currently being projected.

   That being the case, I think that using the simple past instead, in this context, would not change the meaning.
2. It was clearly not the job for which his age and education should have fitted him.

   With regards to *should*, I would assert that it's again about propriety, rather than desire, as in the first example - they're both closer to expectation.

   These days, I think we would say *suited* rather than fitted, although I understand the meaning.

   I don't think using "fits" for a job is as idiomatic today, as "suits" is.

   However, *if* the distribution and usage is the same, I would guess that your proposed sentence would be acceptable. It's a bit of an edge case, though.

Comment: _Propriety_ means "socially acceptable" here?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng This is a really tough one, for me - it's not about capability, or possibility, or desirability. But it actually, I think, doesn't have the connotation of expectation, the more I think of it. It's almost as though it's being used emphatically. _Tricky one._

Comment: If it's so tricky even for a native speaker, maybe it's not worth considering it too much. We could wait and see other possible answers. Thx! @jimsug

Comment: Yup - I'll note, if anyone decides to pursue this, that it's because of the historical context that I'm having issues - I'm not entirely sure whether it has the same connotations now as it did then, but I'd be inclined to think that it didn't, based on distribution.

Comment: In retrospect, "should have fitted" sounds more like a modern use, like in "The shop is closed. I should've come earlier. ". I guess it is only **fitted** that makes you feel the second example dated. What do you think? @jimsug

Comment: @KinzleB That's more or less what I said, right?

Comment: if I say "I would've thought it is hot in here, but it turns out to be quite cold", does this sound dated to you?

Comment: Not dated, but it's still at least unusual, if not ungrammatical. You can ask a new question :)

Comment: I will before I find out if I didn't misunderstand your answer here. :-) You meant the two "should have" in my cited examples share the sam usage? or the second one is a different one? @jimsug

Comment: I didn't contemplate whether they shared the same usage, beyond the fact that they both conveyed some sense of expectation, as stated in my answer.

Comment: But you also mentioned above "it doesn't have the connotation of expectation". I got confused, so plz clarify it for me. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29583/discussion-between-jimsug-and-kinzle-b).

Answer (score 2):

Constructions using `have` in this manner are indeed common in old literature:

> 'I **should have thought** him a clergyman, but for his having no Reverend here,' said I.
>   <sub>*Source*: Dickens, Charles, [*Hunted Down*](http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Charles_Dickens/Hunted_Down/Chapter_II_p2.html)</sub>
>
> I beg your pardon, Mr. Dashwood, but if he had done otherwise, I **should have thought** him a rascal.
>   <sub>*Source*: Austen, Jane, [*Sense and Sensibility*](http://www.open-bks.com/library/classics/austen_jane_sense/sense-283-284.html)</sub>
>
> If I did not know that the play was Shakespeare's, I **should have thought** it must have been one of those early tragedies of blood and horror from which he is said to have redeemed the stage'?
>   <sub>*Source*: Bradley, A. C. [*Shakespearean Tragedy: Lectures on Hamlet, Othello, King Lear, Macbeth.*](http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/bradley/tr89.html) 2nd ed. London: Macmillan, 1905.</sub>

You are absolutely correct when you suggest substituting `should` with `would` - this is a very idiomatic expression and these `should`s should not be read nor taken literally. These uses of `should have thought` are perfectly equivalent to the use of `would have thought` in this line:

> Yet who **would have thought** the old man to have had so much blood in him?
>   <sub>*Source*: Shakespeare, William, [*Macbeth* V.i.39-40](http://www.shakespeare-navigators.com/macbeth/T51.html)</sub>

In American English, at least - as jimsug has noted - this is language particular to period literature and the discussion thereof, and would never be encountered in daily conversation used in this fashion. Perhaps it may be a more natural expression in some other region (for instance, in London it is apparently fairly common to say "mind the gap" when people are boarding trains, as a way of warning them to be mindful of the gap between the train station platform and the train itself, but in the States using "mind" as a verb is already fairly uncommon, and even more so in this fashion).

The second example uses "should have" in a more modern construction, although the use of "fitted" here is rather dated. I would suggest reading it as

> It was clearly not the job for which his age and education **should have *prepared*** him.

That being said, `should have` is not in itself a wholly antiquated phrase to use, but in modern usage is taken much more literally, and is much more common as a contraction:

> You really **should've** studied for that test instead of staying out all night.
>   Yeah, I **should've** thought of that, but it's too late for that now.
>   Did you at least talk to the professor immediately, like you **should've**?

One might also use `should have` in place of `should've` for a more pronounced effect, as is the case for most contractions (as the Google results for "should have thought" will show).

It's worth noting that in contexts where people are not paying attention to grammar and/or spelling, it's not uncommon to see `should of` where `should've` is the correct phrase to use, because they are pronounced in more or less exactly the same manner.

Comment: As a note: the third example I listed (Bradley 1905) is something of a hybrid between the dated and modern usage of the phrase (that is, it can be read both emphatically and literally and makes sense both ways).

Comment: You say it can be read emphatically, so emphasize what? @Samuel Lijin

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng, emphatically in the sense that "should have" is not to be taken literally but simply a clause that emphasizes the rest of the thought, as it is in the other examples.

Comment: Hey, Samuel. I don't know if you still visit this site. I'd like to ask you a question. I've consulted jimsug. He said it was "nearer fiity", "thought him younger" and "fitted" that sounded dated. As an AmE speaker, do you feel these "should have thought" dated to your ears? @Samuel

Comment: Yes; the elaborate sentence structure which adds unnecessary words in their particular fashion also contributes.

Comment: Thx for your reply. :-) I noticed the examples you gave shares the same subject "I". I think these "should" are past form of "shall". In modern style, I would reword your examples: But for his having no Reverend, I **would have thought** he was a clergyman; If he had done otherwise, I **would have thought** he was a rascal; If I hadn't know that the play was Shakespeare's, I **would have thought** it must have been one of those early tragedies; If nobody had revealed he was a twisted killer, who **would have thought** the old man to have had so much blood on his hands? Am I right? @Samuel

Comment: You would be better off asking a new question about that: I don't know enough about the mechanisms of English grammar to answer that. Going off my gut, though, the "should have [past tense verb]" construction does not use "should" as the past tense of "shall" but rather as a conditional verb.