# "should have taken seriously"

Tags: past-tense, subjunctives

*It is not really puzzling that Benjamin **should have taken** such authors seriously; virtually everyone – including the avant-garde – was drinking from the murky waters in the interwar period.*

From the preceding paragraph it follows that Benjamin really "took such authors" (the ones with reactionary and right-wing beliefs) seriously. But does not the usage of "should have" in my sentence indicate actually the opposite?

Comment: *Should* here does not have a counterfactual implication--you may understand it as the present-day English equivalent of a subjunctive in languages which have distinct inflections for that. It would mean exactly the same thing if the author had written *It is not really puzzling that Benjamin **took** such authors seriously*, or *For Benjamin to have taken such authors seriously is not really puzzling*.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. Is there some reason why the author chose this form? Is it only a matter of a style?

Comment: @StoneyB: *It's interesting [that] you [**should**] say that*. Suppose we switch to present tense and change the embedded subject to a pronoun where the verb form doesn't match the subjunctive / infinitive, giving *It's interesting that **he** should **say** that*. In that case, the presence of ***should*** obliges us to use the uninflected verb form (where *without* it, we'd have the normally-conjugated *that he **says** that*). So I think it's not just that OP could *think of it* as a subjunctive - it really ***is** a subjunctive*.

Comment: I'd say it's mostly stylistic; but it does convey a minor sort of modality, just a hint of a concession that it was certainly possible for Benjamin **not** to have taken these authors seriously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the plainform there is an infinitive, elicited by use with an auxiliary: it would be exactly the same form if you found it interesting that he *can* say that or that he *does* say that.

Comment: @StoneyB: oic. Yeah - it's the fact of there being an *auxiliary* verb (and that we don't inflect more than one verb in such "multiple-verb" constructions). I suggest this be classed as yet another nail in the subjunctive's coffin! :)

Comment: What about changing the sentence as *it's not really puzzling for Benjamin to have taken ...*?

Comment: I'd avoid this: *puzzling for Benjamin* can be misunderstood as saying that  Benjamin was puzzled.

Comment: A subset of the consuetudinal: it was SOP to drink from the murky waters.

Comment: This may help you: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30399/should-have-in-a-factual-sense and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/two-usages-of-should-have-done @bart-leby

Answer (score 0):

> "But does not the usage of "should have" in my sentence indicate actually the opposite?"

No. This author's florid and fussy style of writing has caused frustration and confusion in the past. I'm sorry you have to read and/or translate this book. The writing is truly awful.

Put simply, ***in this context***, **"should have taken"** means **"took."**

StoneyB and FumbleFingers have commented at length already on why this is so, but the answer remains the same, regardless of the reason.